# CryptoJS aes encrypt function PHP equivalent

Tags: javascript, php, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to create a PHP equivalent to this JS code with CryptoJS:

```
function aesEncrypt (data) {
   const key = 'GSTEGSTEjdfheyhdHSHSHSHDHHDHmdjjdn12ndndn5r=';
   const iv = '\0';
   
   const cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key), {
       iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv), // parse the IV 
       padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
       mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
   })
   
   return cipher.toString()
}
```

result of the js code :  pHjpwiyKq7Rf4dFcBMbm1w==

here is the PHP code I wrote by reading other stackoverflow questions. But it did not return the same result.

```
    $plaintext  = "plainText";
    $method     = 'aes-256-cbc';
    
    $key = base64_encode("GSTEGSTEjdfheyhdHSHSHSHDHHDHmdjjdn12ndndn5r=");
    $iv  = hex2bin('00000000000000000000000000000000');
            
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
                                   $plaintext,
                                   $method,
                                   $key,
                                   OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
                                   $iv
                                );
    
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);
    
    echo $ciphertext;
```

result of the PHP code :  +YJOMi2vISmEXIjUZls3MA==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP code, the key must be Base64 **de**coded and not Base64 encoded:

```php
$key = base64_decode("GSTEGSTEjdfheyhdHSHSHSHDHHDHmdjjdn12ndndn5r=");
```

With this change the desired ciphertext is created.

Note that the ciphertext is Base64 encoded by default if `0` is passed instead of `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` in the fourth parameter of the [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) call. The explicit Base64 encoding of the ciphertext is then not necessary.

---

Keep in mind that a static IV is insecure. Usually during encryption a *random* IV is generated, which is passed to the decrypting side along with the ciphertext (typically concatenated).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function encryptData($data, $key, $iv) {
  $cipher = "aes-256-cbc";
  $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;

  $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $cipher, $key, $options, $iv);
  $encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted);

  return $encrypted;
}

$message = "Message";
$key = "mysecretkey";
$iv = "myiv";

$encrypted = encryptData($message, $key, $iv);

echo $encrypted;
```

Comment: Please addsome explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).